# iOS create custom/compound action. scripting? activator addon?

Tags: ios, scripting, jailbreak, ios5

Though I am a programmer, I have never written for any Apple device.  As such, my iOS-specific knowledge and familiarity with their API is nearly non-existent so please bear with me.

I would like to create an action from the lock screen (swipe, double tap clock, whatever) that would unlock and immediately open the App Switcher (I am not interested in extensions ala SwitcherPlus or the like).  I guess this means writing a small script, and I could use some help concerning the API and other basics (the core features, shouldn't need any fringe stuff).  While I am willing to get into the nitty gritty if need be, I am open to other solutions.  Even something as high-level as chaining several Activator responses together would be fine.

I see `Ruby` under Cydia/Scripting (Telesphoreo).  Though I'd slightly prefer Python or even Bash, being that my purposes are fairly minor Ruby would be just fine.  I would rather not use Objective-C.  While my original goal is the behavior described above, I can see myself wanting to do similar things in the future so some tips towards general know-how would be much appreciated.

If it is not clear, this a purely personal project.  I am not at all concerned with packaging, sharing, backwards compatibility, commercial appeal, etc

PS - I have, until this point, set my Cydia viewing to "hacker" but not "dev".  Does this endeavor indicate that I should up it to dev?   The term seems a little generous, but if it opens up packages that I will need...

---

EDIT: I use an iPhone 4S, iOS 5.0.1

Comment: sorry if the question is a little vague, but if I knew enough to ask a more pointed question I'd probably know enough that I wouldn't have to ask =P

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible in any scripting language. For one reason: You'll need to do code injection to achieve these goals (MobileSubstrate).

1) If you want to detect user interaction, you'll have to add ways to detect it or hook implementations which are already there. Even if you just wanna use Activator, you'll still have to develop a binary to register itself with Activator -> objC

2) There is no known way (at least to me) to interact with SpringBoard via scripts the way you want. So you'll have to make a binary which would execute the opening of the switcher.

I hope someone will have a better answer for you, but I'm very very sure that you won't get around using C/objC

There is a tool called http://www.cycript.org/ which is a bridge between JavaScript and objC, but I have never seen it being used for more than investigating.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Not happy to hear it, but you're probably right. Just kind of disappointing - I don't need to get my hooks into the iOS that deeply, even something like an "Activator GUI" would be more than enough.  What you've described seems like overkill, at least from an intuitive glance.  I am sure that there are reasons, however, and that what you've said is correct. It seems that, to use the parlance of Cydia, there is plenty out there for User, and likewise for Developer. But for the computer literate, but lacking specific knowledge, Hacker? Not so much.

Comment: All the things you wanna do are simple hacking.
The thing is that SpringBoard (the iOS UI) (that's where all this stuff has to happen) has no way of interacting with scripts, simply because it wasn't build for that. 
So someone would have to make a tweak which would act as a bridge between your script and SpringBoard.

Comment: Oh, and btw. there is a tool in Cydia called Activator (that's what I meant by Activator early), but objC is needed to register actions with it.

Comment: @YillerDev I use Activator, and that's what's so frustrating.  Each of the actions I would like to do are supported by Activator, but I cannot see a way (nor have I been able to find thru Googling or iPhone forums) to perform a sequence of more than one.

Comment: then it would probably easier to contact rpetrich if he could set up something so you can launch a chain of actions with a single gesture

Comment: he is Activator author?  good idea.    in case you are curious, this tweak called TerminalActivator looks like it has some promise: http://wowmobi.net/iphone/iphone-tutorials/how-to-use-activator-actions-via-terminal/     i think ill probably need to package a mini-app to run the shell script, but that appears to be manageable (hopefully lock screen restrictions won't be too much of an issue).  learning the real nuts and bolts of MobileSubstrate, Objective-C, etc. just felt like overkill